# PostgreSQL Create A Line Column From Two Point Columns

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin

My database has beginning and end points [beginning(x,y) ending(x,y)]. I want to create lines from this database for each beginning-end points.

I tried `ST_MAKELINE` but this function wants location as text as said in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195807/how-to-create-a-line-into-a-table-in-postgis). I don't want to enter the points one by one.

How can I pull points from database?

[image: database]

Comment: no no, [`ST_MakeLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) requires 2 geometries, which could be constructed from text (as in the linked question) or simply be consumed from existing column(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is call `st_makeline` on both geom fields:

```
SELECT st_makeline(geom, a_geom) as geom
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Thanks! Query returned successfully. I missed this "as geom"part.  I got this.

Comment: @BensuGayret it's not really necessary. If you don't do that, you'll still get a geom field, but it'll be called st_makeline